# Entity framework Making use of linq to entities?

Tags: entity-framework

I have heard about linq to entities .
Is entity framework Making use of linq to entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ to Entities is one of the ways of querying in Entity Framework.

```
var user = from u in context.Users
           where u.Id = userId
           select u;
```

and

```
var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId);
```

Are both examples of LINQ to Entities. The `context` variable is the Entity Framework `ObjectContext`.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to Entities is part of the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

better you read

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @SLaks: It has to be some error in the documentation because EF is part of .NET since version 3.5 SP1 = Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Comment: this is an excerpt from that page which responds to the question: `As we discussed in the section on ADO.NET Entity Framework Object Services, the upcoming version of ADO.NET includes a layer that can expose database data as regular .NET objects. Furthermore, ADO.NET tools will generate .NET classes that represent the EDM schema in the .NET environment. This makes the object layer an ideal target for LINQ support, allowing developers to formulate queries against a database right from the programming language used to build the business logic. This capability is known as LINQ to Entities. `